# SSRS compatibility with Edge

Tags: reporting-services, microsoft-edge

We use SQL Server 2012 and using version 44.17763.831.0 of Microsoft Edge. Edge, it would appear is supported for viewing reports but not for managing them. The screenshot below shows how in IE we are able to click on the drop down menu and edit a report, this does not work in Edge.
[image]

Does anyone know of a way around this or if the latest version of Edge now supports this? Or perhaps upgrading SQL server would help?

Comment: `SQL Server 2012` there's your problem right there.

Comment: So an upgrade to SQL server 2014 should get things working?

Comment: Almost certainly not - SQL 2012 is EOL, SQL 2014 is EOL, so why would you expect that upgrading one EOL product to another EOL product would fix the issue? What you actually need to do is upgrade to preferably SQL 2019, or at least SQL 2016 (which goes EOL in 4 months, so not a great option) - or simply not use Edge.

Comment: Thanks Ian, we currently use IE which as you'll know is being retired in August this year. We have the option of Chrome at work too but that also produces the same problem with SSRS

Comment: SSRS 2012 is a rather old version of SSRS, the UI is not so fit for modern browsers.  To have better UI and web portal management for modern browsers, I would suggest you upgrade to SQL Server 2017/ 2019 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I was using SQL SERVER 2008 with IE. So I downloaded the IE TAB extension to chrome and all SSRS features were working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Microsoft Edge Settings
Search for "Internet Explorer Compatibility"
Under "Internet Explore mode pages" add you SSRS pages address that need to be open under IE

All set.
That's it :)

Comment: This does not work as expected. Site loads fine but the ability to manage reports does not work in an IE compatible tab of Edge. :(

Answer (score 0):

I've just found the same issue, after not having accessed the SSRS browser front end for a while.

I followed the same process as Keivan Kamkari.

The browser restarts. After that I am able to use the dropdown for the report or folder and access the 'Manage' option.

In my case, I wanted to examine the parameters settings. I was able to do this and correct the issue that my colleague was having.

There is a warning to tell you that you are in IE mode, as well as an IE logo in the corner of the tab, but it is in the Edge browser and is open alongside my other Edge tabs.